# If $C$ is a Clifford circuit, is there necessarily a Clifford circuit $C'$ such that $CT=TC'$?

Tags: quantum-gate, clifford-group

Let $C$ be a Clifford circuit, is there necessarily a Clifford circuit $C'$ such that $CT=TC'$ (where $T$ is taken as applying the $T$ gate to the same qubit on both sides)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

There always exists a unique unitary $U$ such that $CT=TU$. Namely, $U = T^\dagger C T$. The question is whether $U$ is Clifford. It turns out that this is not guaranteed. For a simple counterexample take Hadamard for $C$. Then

$$
U=T^\dagger H T = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & e^{i\pi/4} \\
e^{-i\pi/4} & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

is not Clifford, because $U|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle+e^{-i\pi/4}|1\rangle\right)$ is not one of the stabilizer states $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|+\rangle$, $|-\rangle$, $|{+i}\rangle$ and $|{-i}\rangle$.

Comment: Caution: this is correct, but sensitive to details of the question that may not be intentional. In particular, if $C^\prime$ were allowed to include an ancilla qubit initialized to $|+\rangle$ and were allowed to move the T gate to the ancilla and were allowed to do measure+feedback then it becomes possible because you can inject a T state and do T gate teleportation.

Comment: @CraigGidney Can you please elaborate? Although this is not what I intended in the question, I'd really love to see more detail.

Comment: I think @CraigGidney is referring to the construction shown in circuit $(14)$ on page 6 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0002039) and also in figure 10.25 on page 486 in Nielsen & Chuang.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Thanks!

Comment: @CraigGidney Just to see if I got this right, does your comment imply that for every Clifford circuit $C$ on $n$ qubits and $i\in \{0,...,n-1\}$, $CT$ (with $T$ applied on the $i$th wire) equals $TC'$ where $C'$ is Clifford on $n+1$ qubits and $T$ is applied to the $i$th wire as well?

Comment: @ttttttttttt It would probably help if you drew a picture. The key thing is that any T gate can be implemented by consuming a T state provided to the circuit, so all the non-clifford parts are in the creation of the T states instead of mixed in with the rest of the circuit.

Comment: @CraigGidney I think that I'm starting to understand, but there is still one point that puzzles me: if you look at circuit (14) on page 6 in the paper suggested above by Adam, it seems like $C'$ will now include measurement gates, but then, doesn't it mean that it's no longer Clifford?

Comment: @ttttttttttt Right, it would technically be a stabilizer circuit instead of a Clifford circuit.